# spark-ml naive bayes save to hdfs

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib, apache-spark-ml

I know through spark-mllib we can save naive bayes model to hdfs by save() method . But we I try with spark-ml naive bayes to save into hdfs then it giving error .
Wrong FS: hdfs://localhost:8020/pa/model/nb, expected: file:///

I am using spark-1.6.0 and hadoop 2.7 .

Answer (score 1):

I've also had problems saving spark-ml models - there doesn't seem to be a straightforward way to do this.

Try saving it like this - if you are getting an error with the path, try saving it to tmp, like below.

```
sc.parallelize(Seq(NBmodel), 1).saveAsObjectFile(“/tmp/NBModel”)
```